# What are N and M parameters in a Baud rate generator?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl, baud-rate

I'm trying to understand how an UART for RS232 works in HDL.

It uses a baud rate generator which generates the especific baud rate you want, right? like 9600, 115200, ...

This is the code where appears always in a Baud rate generator:

```
module mod_m_counter
#(
    parameter N = 4,
    parameter M = 10
 )
 (
    input  wire clk, reset,
    output wire max_tick,
    output wire [N-1:0] q
 );

reg [N-1:0] r_reg;
wire [N-1:0] r_next;

always@( posedge clk, posedge reset )
    if( reset )
        r_reg <= 0;
    else
        r_reg <= r_next;

assign r_next = ( r_reg == (M-1) ) ? 0 : r_reg + 1;

assign q = r_reg;

assign max_tick = ( r_reg == (M-1) ) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

endmodule
```

I don't understand what N and M are?

If for example I want to generate a 9600 baud rate, which N and M should I choose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The module name is very descriptive of what it does: `mod_m_counter` is a counter with modulus `M` (i.e. it counts from 0 to M-1). When the count value equals M-1, the `max_tick` signal is raised.

`N` should equal `ceil(log2(M-1))`, as is represents the number of bits needed to store values up to and including M-1.

Comment: Ok. `N = ceil(log2(M-1))` but where does M come? M should be related with my clock (50Mhz) and the baud rate 19200, but I can't find the relation.

Comment: Would depend on your symbol width and what other modules are in the system. Note that usually these parameters are set by the higher-level module that instantiated it, overriding the default values. Assuming this controlled some 16-bit UART, you could try M=325 (`50,000k/(16*9.6k)`)

Answer (score 1):

To understand this, you must first understand the relation between mod-n counter and input frequency F.

> A Mod-N counter will divide the Input Frequency F, by N. So Mod-n
>   Counter is a Frequency Divider, and Output Frequency will be F/N.

UART will be used with a Micro-Processor or inside a Micro-Controller.

Now typically, current Micro-Processor speeds are in terms of GHz and current Micro-Controller speeds are in terms of KHz. But UART speeds are very very less than the Controller/Processor speeds.

**That's why you need to have lower frequency than CPU speed for UART module, and to get that lower frequency, this mod Counters are used.**

Now to know, which value you should write to M, N for a specific baud rate, can be decided, only by checking out the specs of the module.